# SQL GROUP BY and MIN to find people with minimum salary in each department

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, subquery, aggregate-functions

I have a sql query that outputs employees who have the minimum salary across departments. It does so by finding the minimum salary for each department and finding people with salaries that match ANY of those. In this case, Person 1 can belong to department A and have a salary of 70k (even though her department's minimum is 45k) and be returned in the query if another department's minimum salary is 70k. However, what if I instead want to output names of people who have the minimum salary for their respective department (so Person 1 would not be returned anymore). Here is the current sql query:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, salary, department_id  
FROM employees  
WHERE salary IN  
( SELECT MIN(salary)  
FROM employees  
GROUP BY department_id 
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead  fo a  IN clause you can also use an inner join

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, salary, department_id  
FROM employees  
INNER JOIN ( SELECT department_id, MIN(salary)  min_sal
FROM employees  
GROUP BY department_id 
) t on t.department_id =employees.department_id  
    and employees.salary = t.min_sal;
```

this  should be better for performance

Comment: Awesome! I like the inner join idea -- it is clear and intuitive. Can you explain what the upper and lowercase "T" represents in the query? Thanks!

Comment: the t  ( i have updated  with lower  case  ... but mysq is case insensitive)  .. is  a table alias  name  .. the table name  is required  by from clause and i have use  just  the char t for the related  table name alias ..hope is clear .. let me know

Comment: Awesome, and yes it is!

Answer (score 2):

If you have MySQL 8.0 then the simplest approach is using window function:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY department_id ORDER BY salary DESC) AS r
      FROM tab) sub
WHERE r = 1;
```

Or:

```
SELECT  first_name, last_name, salary, department_id  
FROM employees e
WHERE (department_id,salary) IN  
      ( SELECT department_id, MIN(salary)  
        FROM employees
        GROUP BY department_id);
```

Comment: I am a SQL noob and found out from this that you can pass `tuples` with `IN`...  this is more valuable than it seems